# Hide form content until button is clicked

Tags: javascript, forms, button

I would like to hide the content of my form until the button is clicked, the code I am using shows content until clicked, I am starting out so probably missing something simple, any help appreciated, the code I am using is:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You need to bind your `myFunction` to the click event of a button. Otherwise, you just declare a function but never invoke it.

Comment: Can you send me your entire HTML code?

Comment: Did you set```#myDIV``` to ```display: none;```  initially?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must add "display: none;" to "myDiv" property in css file then you can use your func

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display == "none" || x.style.display == "") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
 border:solid 1px #c0c0c0;
 padding:10px;
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction();" value="switch" /><br>
<div id="myDIV">Welcome</div>
```

Because, if `display` is decalred in `css` to `none` (or whatever but not in `DOM` element) then `javascript` will "see" it like empty string. Or, set in `<div id="myDIV" style="display:none;"></div>`.
By my opinon, first code is better choice.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need
Heres the code:

```js
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function() {
document.getElementById("myInput").style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" id="myInput" style="display: none;">
</form>
<button id="myButton">Click</button>
```